# How to save Sessions in PHP for a Single page Application of Angular 2

Tags: php, angular, session, post

In Angular2 App when i am logging in from my LoginComponent, the Session variable gets created successfully in the PHP server.

But when my app changes its route to some other component (For Eg: SchoolsListComponent ) and then it requests something from PHP server, i notice that session variable is not present at all.

Below error occurs when i call get_schools_list.php from my SchoolListComponent

> Undefined index: id in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\admin\session_secure.php** on line
>   **3**

In PHP Server i have following files

1. login.php.
2. session_secure.php.
3. get_schools_list.php.
4. angular_cors_fix.php.
5. db_connect.php.

In Angular2 i have following components

1. LoginComponent.
2. SchoolsListComponent.

Here is the code of each file

1. LoginComponent Class:

   ```
   phpUrl = "http://192.168.43.162/myapp/admin/";
   login(username:string, password:string){
      let postdata = {
        username : username,
        password : password
      }
      let headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
      return this.http.post(`${this.phpUrl}loginAdmin.php`,postdata,{
        headers : headers
      }).subscribe(
          (response : Response)=>{
             let data = response.json();
             if(data.success == 1){
                this.router.navigate(["/schools_list"]); //Routing to My Main Component
             }
          }
      );
   }
   ```
2. SchoolListComponent Class:

   ```
   phpUrl = "http://192.168.43.162/myapp/admin/";
   constructor(){ this.getSchools(); }
   getSchools(){
      let post_data = {
          some_post_data : "data"
      }
      let headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
      let myObserver = this.http.post(`${this.phpUrl}get_schools_list.php`,post_data,{
        headers : headers
      });

      myObserver.subscribe(
        (data : Response)=>{
          let session = data.json();
          if(session.loggedIn == false){
            this.router.navigate(["/login"]);
          }
        }
      );
      return myObserver;
   }
   ```
3. login.php

   ```
   <?php
   require "angularfix.php";
   require "db_connect.php";
   $response = array();
   $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
   $username = $data->username;
   $password = $data->password;
   if (!preg_match('/[\'^£$%&*()}{#~?><>,|=+¬-]/', $username)){    
      $query ="SELECT * FROM `admin` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password'";
      if($result = mysqli_query($database,$query)){
          if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
              $response['success'] = 1;
              $response['message'] = "Successfully logged in !!";
              $response['admin_id'] = $row['admin_id'];
              session_start();
              $_SESSION['id']=session_id();//Here i initialized session id
              $response['id'] = $_SESSION['id'];
              $response['savepath'] = session_save_path();
              storeIntoSessionAdminId($response['admin_id']);

          }else{
              $response['success'] = 0;
              $response['message'] = "Username or Password Invalid";
              $response['error'] = "Username or Password Invalid";
          }
      }else{
          $response['success'] = 0;
          $response['message'] = "Error in Server";
          $response['error'] = "".mysqli_error($database)."";
      }
   }else{
      $response['error'] = "Special characters not allowed";
      $response['success'] = 0;
   }
   // echoing JSON response
   echo json_encode($response);
   function storeIntoSessionAdminId($id){
       $_SESSION['admin_id']=$id;
   }
   ?>
   ```
4. session_secure.php

   ```
   <?php
   session_start();
   $response = array();
   if($_SESSION['id'] == session_id()){
       $response['admin_id'] = $_SESSION['admin_id'];
       $response["loggedIn"] = true;
       $response['message'] = "user has session !!!";
       $response['success'] = 1;
   }
   else{
       $response["loggedIn"] = false;
       $response['message'] = "user dont have any session !!!";
       $response['success'] = 0;
       echo json_encode($response);
       exit();
   }
   ?>
   ```
5. get_schools_list.php

   ```
   <?php
   require "angular_cors_fix.php";
   require "session_secure.php";
   require "db_connect.php";   
   $response["schools"] = array();
   $query = "SELECT * FROM school";
   if($result = mysqli_query($database,$query)){
       if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){
           while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
               $temp                   = array();
               $temp["school_id"]      = $row["school_id"];
               $temp["school_name"]    = $row["school_name"];
               $temp["data_phase"]     = $row["data_phase"];
               $temp["school_address"] = $row["school_address"];
               $temp["city"]           = $row["city"];
               $temp["pincode"]        = $row["pincode"];
               $temp["total_students"] = $row["total_students"];
               $temp["head_name"]      = $row["head_name"];
               array_push($response["schools"],$temp);
           }
           $response['success'] = 1;
           $response['message'] = "Data Available";
       }else{
           $response['success'] = 0;
           $response['message'] = "Data Not Available";
       }
   }
   $response["success"] = 1;
   $response["message"] = "Data Available";
   echo json_encode($response);
   ?>
   ```
6. angular_cors_fix.php :

   ```
   <?php
      header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
      header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
      header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
   ?>
   ```
7. db_connect.php :

   ```
   <?php
     date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
     $database = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'myapp')
        or die(mysqli_error($database));   
   ?>
   ```

Flow of my App is as Follow

1. LoginComponent :

   - Login Request to Server "Login.php" which creates session.
   - Redirect to SchoolListComponent on Successful Login.
2. SchoolListComponent :

   - Request server for Schools JSON, and also check the session
   - if session is not present redirect to LoginComponent.
   - if session is present then show schools list in template.

I have pasted all files because, i thought the problem may be due to multiple reasons like :

1. CORS issue.
2. Single Page Application.
3. Headers
4. PHP Sessions.
5. Angular2 / PHP itself.

Please guide me how to resolve this issue of sessions thank you..

Comment: $_SESSION['id'] where are you setting session  variable?

Comment: in Login.php i am setting $_SESSION['id']

Comment: Since you're uisng angular what need of using php  session ?

Comment: I think to validate Users of my app from server side.I dont know if using PHP with Angular2 is right.Please let me know ..

Comment: you just going to check whether user is avaliable or not right for that why you need session ?

Comment: My app is a web app so if someone opens a url For Eg: "http://myapp.com/schools" then everyone will be able to see the data of schools on that page. So i m just checking that whoever has opened that url is a valid user, and to do this Sessions are required. No bro, I want to check if user is valid or not

Comment: you can maintain session in angular itself no need of php session

Comment: ohh, then how??. I will check how to do that, but right now let me know if it is possible using PHP